# Duplicate class error when both axistools and clover plugin are included in maven project

Tags: clover

We have a maven project which uses clover and axistools-wsdl2java plugin. Platfrom is windows.

We are using clover 2.4.0 plugin to get code coverage which integrated in project's pom.xml. 
Configured the clover plugin as shown below.

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.4.0</version> 
    <configuration> <generatePdf>true</generatePdf> 
    <generateXml>true</generateXml> 
    <generateHtml>true</generateHtml> 
    <licenseLocation>C:/EcasSVNCO/ews/ews-mvn/ewsbase/src/test/resources/license/clover.license</licenseLocation> 
    <reportDescriptor>C:/EcasSVNCO/ews/ews-mvn/ewsbase/src/test/resources/descriptor/default-clover-report.xml</reportDescriptor> 
    <excludes> 
        <exclude>${basedir}/src/main/java/*.java</exclude> 
    </excludes> 
    </configuration> 
        <executions> 
            <execution> 
                <id>install</id> 
                <phase>install</phase> 
                <goals> 
                    <goal>instrument</goal> 
                    <goal>clover</goal> 
                </goals> 
            </execution> 
            <!--
            <execution> 
                <id>test</id> 
                <phase>test</phase> 
                <goals> 
                    <goal>instrument</goal> 
                    <goal>clover</goal> 
                </goals> 
             </execution> 
             <execution> 
                <id>site</id> 
                <phase>pre-site</phase> 
                <goals> 
                    <goal>instrument</goal> 
                    <goal>clover</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution> 
            -->
        </executions> 
</plugin>
```

Also, there is axistools plugin used to generate classes using wsdl file, which is configured as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${base.dir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${base.dir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFiles>wsecas.wsdl</wsdlFiles>
        </wsdlFiles>


        <packageSpace>com.symantec.wsecas</packageSpace>
        <testCases>true</testCases>
        <serverSide>true</serverSide>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <subPackageByFileName>true</subPackageByFileName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When we execute a command 'mvn clean install' , compilation will go fine. Then first axistool's wsdl2java goal is ran and source files are generated in respective directory.
Next clover plugin tries to instrument the source code by running unit test cases, when this plugin places the instrumented source code under 
{basedir}/target/clover/src/main/java/...
Then it fires "compile" goal to compile all the source code. While compiling the source code, two source paths are getting added i.e.
{basedir}/src/main/java/... and {basedir}/target/clover/src/main/java/... , both have same classes. 
When maven compiler tries to compile these sources compilation is failing by throwing "Duplicate Class Error".

But when we comment out axistools plugin, clover instrumentation and report generation goes fine.

If any of you have come across similar issue 'Duplicate class error', please guide us on this regard. 
Any suggestion and help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that your Axis plugin generates sources to src/main/java (it should be rather a target/src-generated).

When the Clover is invoked it will first take 'normal' sources from src/main/java, instrument them and put into target/clover/java. Next Clover will change list of source roots replacing src/main/java by target/clover/java.

Next the AXIS code generation comes into play and it generates new sources again into src/main/java adding also this directory as extra source root.

As a consequence a compiler sees the same set of sources (i.e. non-generated ones) in two locations and complains about it.

This case is very similar to the one described in Clover's Knowledge Base:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVERKB/Duplicate+class+errors+with+Clover+and+JAXB+or+JAXB2+plugin

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVERKB/Duplicate+class+errors+with+Clover+and+jaxws-maven+plugin

you will find possible solutions in these articles.